# Excerpt Length & List Category Posts Plugin

Tags: shortcode, excerpt, plugin-list-category-post

I'm trying to filter out the excerpt by character length for a plugin called "List Category Posts". I've been trying to get the excerpts working for the past week, but nothing is doing the trick.  The plugin actually comes with a feature that allows you to post the excerpt or not, then filter it by character length.. by adding "excerpt_size=" in the shortcode.  But unfortunately, it doesn't work at this time, and I've tested it with multiple different themes.  Anyways, here is the code it uses to get the excerpt:

```
public function get_excerpt($single){
    if (
            $this->params['excerpt']=='yes' &&
            !($this->params['content']=='yes' &&
            $single->post_content) ){
        /*
         * Strip shortcodes - #5
         * http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes
        */
        if($single->post_excerpt){
            return $single->post_excerpt;
        }
        $lcp_excerpt = strip_shortcodes(strip_tags($single->post_content));
        $exc_lim = intval($this->params['excerpt_size']);
        $lcp_excerpt = mb_substr($lcp_excerpt, 0, $exc_lim) . '...';
        return $lcp_excerpt;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the excerts are set by default like so (I've tried changing the 'excerpt_size' default parameter below, and it did not work):

```
'excerpt' => 'no',
'excerpt_size' => '255',
```

I don't even need a grand solution to get the whole shortcode excerpt filter to work with any number I enter.  If anyone could help me get it to work so all the excerpt character lengths are say, 100.  That would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have

```
'excerpt' => 'yes',
'excerpt_size' => '100',
'content' => 'no'
```

... when `get_excerpt` runs. You can set `$params` like that but what you posted is not all of the code. It is using `$this` which means it is part of a class (or you'd get errors). Somewhere in that class something might be altering the defaults, and I suspect something does. If that doesn't work you need to edit your question to provide more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Its been almost a decade but just in case anyone else looks this up...there is a parameter excerpt_size that you can add in the shortcode.

Example: [ catlist name=mycategory orderby=date order=desc excerpt_strip=no excerpt_size=857 ]